# Упоминание пользователя в разных лицах

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, мобильная-версия

При просмотре мобильной версии [профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current/) наблюдается как упоминание в первом лице ("вы"), так и в третьем (по нику):

[image: alexolut]

Это кажется довольно странным, упоминать ник пользователя лишний раз при просмотре профиля.

Comment: это точно мобильная версия? У меня все на английском

Comment: @Danis в 2016 году перевод был, потом [слетел](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9759/176217) и 81 строку не очень хочется переводить, надо разбивать. Соответствующий [запрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911) есть на MSE.

Comment: жалко что слетел :(

Answer (score 3):

Согласно [ответу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362111/339911) на MSE должно использоваться местоимение "Вы" в обоих случаях. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что мобильную версию править не будут.