# Отсутствует перевод статистики по голосам в профиле пользователя на мобильной версии

Tags: дефект, локализация, мобильная-версия

Для воспроизведения включить мобильную версию сайта в подвале и перейти в профиль пользователя на вкладку Активность, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063?tab=topactivity

Прокрутить страницу вниз до пункта **Голосов отдано (XXX)**:

> Of the votes cast, 2,987 were upvotes and 200 were downvotes. Андрей NOP voted on questions 1,323 times and 1,864 times on answers.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В полной версии дефекта нет.

Comment: Похожая история и на странице выборов. Там просто [81 строка](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Of%20the%20votes%20cast) на перевод, т.к. каждое числительное имеет 3 формы. Никто этим заниматься не хочет.

Comment: Давным давно фиксилось уже: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3783/176217